# Tkinter error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a `tkinter` window where it checks if the correct string was passed, but if I put the wrong string, then I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row=0, column=0)

def buttonclick():
    if e.get() == "12345":
        goodLabel = Label(root, text="Good!")
        goodLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
    else:
        badLabel = Label(root, "Bad!")
        badLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=buttonclick)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: when you post an error you should post the whole error traceback (starting at word "Traceback") so that we know where the error happened and why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row=0, column=0)

def buttonclick():
    if e.get() == "12345":
        goodLabel = Label(root, text="Good!")
        goodLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)
    else:
        badLabel = Label(root, text="Bad!")
        badLabel.grid(row=3, column=0)

button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=buttonclick)
button.grid(row=2, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Just use `text="Bad!"`
is this what you're looking for??

Comment: is this worked??

Comment: comment if worked.